# Pull a message from an Android handler

Tags: android

How do I remove a queued message of a given type from a handler's message queue?

Comment: By `type` do you mean the `Message.what` value, or the `Message.obj` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the remove*() methods will do :) (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)